# What are some of the branches/areas of mathematics that are built upon the foundation of calculus?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, education

I was pleased to know that calculus is the culmination of an intellectual pursuit that lasted for two thousand years. So, I just got curious that if there are branches which are built upon calculus.

Also, it would be nice if you can briefly tell the type of problems that each of such branch deals with.

Comment: This is ridiculously broad and I vote to close with no further comment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_analysis

Comment: As Rob indicated, this is really quite broad, but if you want to stay within the scope of mathematics and not look too far, direct mathematical fields that are build upon the foundation of calculus (of a real variable) would be Complex analysis towards the analysis side, and Differential Geometry towards the Geometry side. Both courses can be found in the upper undergrad level of math